# Select first two columns from tab-delimited text file and and substitute with '_' character

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a sample input file as follows

```
RF00001 1c2x    C   3   118 77.20   1.6e-20 1   119 f29242
RF00001 1ffk    9   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 8e2511
RF00001 1jj2    9   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 f29242
RF00001 1k73    B   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 8484c0
RF00001 1k8a    B   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 93c090
RF00001 1k9m    B   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 ebeb30
RF00001 1kc8    B   1   121 77.40   1.4e-20 1   119 bdc000
```

I need to extract the second and third columns from the text file and substitute the tab with '_'

Desired output file :

```
1c2x_C  
1ffk_9  
1jj2_9  
1k73_B  
1k8a_B  
1k9m_B  
1kc8_B
```

I am able to print the two columns by :

```
awk -F" " '{ print $2,$3 }' input.txt
```

but unable to substitute the tab with '_' with the following command

```
awk -F" " '{ print $2,'_',$3 }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print $2"_"$3}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="_"} {print $2,$3}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Adding a `sed` solution.

```
sed -E 's/[^ ]* +([^ ]*) +([^ ]*).*/\1_\2/' Input_file
```